# Crash when switching to edit mode after creating mesh from pyscript

Tags: mesh, scripting

I post here since I don't think it's a bug but something I could have done the wrong way...

So I have this script (copy-pasted from somewhere I don't remember, but this is the same I would have done reading the doc) :

```
def createMesh(name, origin, verts, edges, faces):
    me = bpy.data.meshes.new(name+'Mesh')
    ob = bpy.data.objects.new(name, me)
    ob.location = origin
    ob.show_name = True
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(ob)
    me.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)
    me.update(calc_edges=True)
    return ob
```

This is the full script, after executing it on the conole, if I try to switch to edit mode, then, blender crashes :

```
def sumInterval(it):
    s = 0
    for x in it:
        yield s, x
        s += x

T =  [

[ [ [ 2.7082256823778, -29.756011754274, 11.0 ], [ -5.170249427219, 29.321890527704, 0.0 ] ], [ [ -2.4620193839073, -0.43412045761943, 11.0 ], [ -5.170240696852, 29.321892067104, 0.0 ] ], [ [ -2.4620193839073, -0.43412045761943, 11.0 ], [ -5.1702409665746, 29.321893596777, 0.0 ] ], [ [ -7.6322559863329, 28.887773908675, 11.0 ], [ -5.1702322362062, 29.321895136175, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 7.6322641819715, -28.887769401073, 11.0 ], [ -5.1702491687653, 29.321889061942, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 2.4620193839073, 0.4341204315424, 11.0 ], [ -5.1702404383987, 29.321890601343, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 2.4620193839073, 0.4341204315424, 11.0 ], [ -5.1702407085707, 29.321892133564, 0.0 ] ], [ [ -2.7082169651985, 29.756013333797, 11.0 ], [ -5.1702319782027, 29.321893672962, 0.0 ] ] ]
,

[ [ [ -7.6322559863329, -28.887773886323, 0.0 ], [ 5.1702322362063, 29.321895136175, 0.0 ] ], [ [ -2.4620193839073, 0.43412047997117, 0.0 ], [ 5.1702409665746, 29.321893596777, 0.0 ] ], [ [ -2.4620193839073, 0.43412047997117, 0.0 ], [ 5.1702406974891, 29.321892070717, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 2.7082256823778, 29.756011780351, 0.0 ], [ 5.170249427856, 29.321890531317, 0.0 ] ], [ [ -2.7082169651985, -29.75601330772, 0.0 ], [ 5.1702319775657, 29.321893669349, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 2.4620193839073, -0.43412040919065, 0.0 ], [ 5.1702407079336, 29.321892129951, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 2.4620193839073, -0.43412040919065, 0.0 ], [ 5.1702404383987, 29.321890601343, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 7.6322641819715, 28.887769423425, 0.0 ], [ 5.1702491687653, 29.321889061942, 0.0 ] ] ]
,

[ [ [ -7.8059038707809, -29.872581691038, 0.0 ], [ 0.17364788444799, 0.98480780471457, 0.0 ] ], [ [ -7.6322559863329, -28.887773886323, 0.0 ], [ 0.17364788444799, 0.98480780471457, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 2.7082256823778, 29.756011780351, 0.0 ], [ 0.17364847088584, 0.98480770130976, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 2.8818741532637, 30.740819481661, 0.0 ], [ 0.17364847088584, 0.98480770130976, 0.0 ] ], [ [ -2.8818648496465, -30.740821112435, 0.0 ], [ 0.17364788444799, 0.98480780471457, 0.0 ] ], [ [ -2.7082169651985, -29.75601330772, 0.0 ], [ 0.17364788444799, 0.98480780471457, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 7.6322641819715, 28.887769423425, 0.0 ], [ 0.17364847088584, 0.98480770130976, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 7.8059126528574, 29.872577124735, 0.0 ], [ 0.17364847088584, 0.98480770130976, 0.0 ] ] ]
,

[ [ [ 2.8818741532637, -30.740819455584, 11.0 ], [ -0.17364847088584, 0.98480770130976, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 2.7082256823778, -29.756011754274, 11.0 ], [ -0.17364847088584, 0.98480770130976, 0.0 ] ], [ [ -7.6322559863329, 28.887773908675, 11.0 ], [ -0.17364788444799, 0.98480780471457, 0.0 ] ], [ [ -7.8059038707809, 29.872581713389, 11.0 ], [ -0.17364788444799, 0.98480780471457, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 7.8059126528574, -29.872577102383, 11.0 ], [ -0.17364847088584, 0.98480770130976, 0.0 ] ], [ [ 7.6322641819715, -28.887769401073, 11.0 ], [ -0.17364847088584, 0.98480770130976, 0.0 ] ], [ [ -2.7082169651985, 29.756013333797, 11.0 ], [ -0.17364788444799, 0.98480780471457, 0.0 ] ], [ [ -2.8818648496465, 30.740821138512, 11.0 ], [ -0.17364788444799, 0.98480780471457, 0.0 ] ] ]

]

V = [ v[0] for Tx in T for v in Tx ]

E = [ (i, i+1) for o, s in sumInterval(len(Tx) for Tx in T) for i in range(o, o+s) ]

import bpy

def createMesh(name, origin, verts, edges, faces):
    me = bpy.data.meshes.new(name+'Mesh')
    ob = bpy.data.objects.new(name, me)
    ob.location = origin
    ob.show_name = True
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(ob)
    me.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)
    me.update(calc_edges=True)
    return ob

createMesh("Tracks", (0,0,0), V,E,[])
```

This is the crash report :

```
# Blender 2.78 (sub 0), Commit date: 2017-02-24 14:33, Hash e92f235283
bpy.context.area.type = 'CONSOLE'  # Property
bpy.context.space_data.context = 'DATA'  # Property
bpy.ops.sculpt.sculptmode_toggle()  # Operator
bpy.ops.sculpt.sculptmode_toggle()  # Operator
bpy.ops.paint.vertex_paint_toggle()  # Operator
bpy.ops.paint.vertex_paint_toggle()  # Operator
bpy.ops.paint.weight_paint_toggle()  # Operator
bpy.ops.paint.weight_paint_toggle()  # Operator

# backtrace
blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x30) [0x1412490]
blender() [0xa46459]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x33a90) [0x7fcd1c09ba90]
blender(bmesh_disk_edge_append+0) [0xfc3b70]
blender(BM_edge_create+0xda) [0xf9e83a]
blender(BM_mesh_bm_from_me+0x7ca) [0xfb2d4a]
blender(BKE_mesh_to_bmesh+0x87) [0x1173f37]
blender(EDBM_mesh_make+0x4d) [0xc86bcd]
blender(ED_object_editmode_enter+0x207) [0xcbf0a7]
blender() [0xcbf28d]
blender() [0xa4df0a]
blender() [0xa4e42d]
blender() [0xcbf40b]
blender() [0xa4df0a]
blender() [0xa4e42d]
blender() [0xc28922]
blender() [0xc39359]
blender() [0xa4f827]
blender() [0xa4fb48]
blender(wm_event_do_handlers+0x221) [0xa4fea1]
blender(WM_main+0x18) [0xa470a8]
blender(main+0x40f) [0xa2627f]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1) [0x7fcd1c088511]
blender(_start+0x2a) [0xa4314a]
```

any idea ?

Comment: You have 32 vertices but your edges use vertex index from 0 to 32. You should range(o, o+s **- 1**)  I think

Comment: Or E = [ (i, i+1) for i in range( len(V) - 1 ) ]?

Comment: Omg... yes, that's it, I forgot to correct on the script that...
Thanks and sorry for my stupidity ^^

Comment: Don't sorry... that happens to everyone!

Answer (score 2):

I'm reposting the correct reply from @lemon so that it can be accepted as the answer as I had the same issue.

The code creating the edges based on the vertex list should be stopping at o+s-1 like so:

```
E = [ (i, i+1) for o, s in sumInterval(len(Tx) for Tx in T) for i in range(o, o+s-1) ]
```

Otherwise it's referencing a vertex that doesn't exist and Blender crashes when you switch to edit mode.